# Is it safe to call a function in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I don't know much about threads, but I have a function in the main class of my console application called SendProcessCmd(string cmd). In my main() I create a process, and store the StreamWriter as a class member var, and my SendProcessCmd() issues the .WriteLine() commands to it.

I have another thread with a TCP server that listens for connections, then allows these to send commands to the process using Program.SendProcessCmd(). Is it safe to do this?

The safest method I can think of would be to find the running process in my server's thread, create a new StreamWriter, then issue the commands. However, this seems like a rather long way around to do the same thing.

Comment: You should know the basics about threading before doing anything with multiple threads in your own application. Have a look at http://www.albahari.com/threading/ to get a good understanding.

Comment: Agreed Oliver. You are in for a world of hurt if you touch this without knowing what you're doing . . .

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I would like to add to the above advice that working with threads and synchronization is generally considered very low-level (which might or might not be OK, depending on your requirements). If you're working with .NET 4, you might want to have a look at more high-level means of concurrency, such as the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) (see also the [Microsoft patterns & practices publication about the TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx).

Comment: @Oliver Hanappi -- Agreed that good knowledge is necessary, otherwise threading code may contain very obscure and non-reproducible bugs.  +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of threads is that you can always call any function and access any data structure from *any* thread.  There are gotcha's, though:

1. You should always consider concurrency issues, locking and dead-lock avoiding etc.
2. Some functions and data structures (esp. related to Windows programming) cannot be called/accessed from a thread other than the main UI thread; doing so may crash your program or cause an exception

Comment: This made a lot more sense. Just for clarification, any function that is not assigned to a new thread is part of the Main thread correct? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Brett Powell, threads don't really have anything to do with functions and data.  Threads are different from processes in that they operate in the same memory space within the same process.  Some *functions*, though, save or access special data within the *thread* (called thread-local storage). Consequently, you cannot call these functions from another thread because they won't have those thread-local data and the function will fail.  Typically you don't use thread-local data yourself, which means that your functions/data can be accessed from any thread.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you correctly, it sounds like both threads will be using the same StreamWriter. If that is correct, then you will need to at the very least synchronise the writes to the StreamWriter using a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx).

If each thread is using multiple calls to the Write method to build up a complete message you need to block other threads from writting for the entire duration that it takes to complete the component parts of the message otherwise your message components will become mixed-up, it is like having two people trying to write on the same piece of paper at the same time in the same location, each writting a different story.

Answer (score 1):

Executing any code and accessing memory is all perfectly fine for any number of threads to do simultaneously. The thing you have to watch out for is two threads trying to write to the same area of memory

Comment: Oh yea sorry, thats true too.

Comment: Also you have to be careful with API calls too. My answer sucked :/